# Providing interface for objects within objects

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller, facade

I am creating a model as in MVC which is made of other objects. My single main model object contains the constituents object. My question is should I be asking the main model object for all the operations that will actually be carried out by constituents object or should I ask for the constituents objects and run its operations? I can see in the first approach, the main model will have to account for all the operations of its constituents modules and will result in adding many functions which will simply delegate to the constituent objects.

Let me explain with an example which is very close to what I am doing. This code below is on fly so please ignore c++ syntax mistakes if any.

```
class Arm
{
public:

    Move(int x, int y);
}

class Robot
{
public:
    Arm leftArm;
    Arm rightArm;

    // should this function be there?
    MoveLeftArm(int x, int y)
    {
        leftArm.Move(x,y);
    }

    // and likewise this?
    MoveRightArm(int x, int y)
    {
        rightArm.Move(x,y);
    }
}

// in the view when I want to move robot arms, should I do this
robot->MoveLeftArm(x,y);
//or this
robot.leftArm.Move(x,y);
```

A dump question but should it depend on how many operations the constituents objects actually support? Also since we are it, is this also an example of facade design pattern?

My concerns:

- First approach can grow the main object to very large object. Do we really want such a large object with so many methods?
- This sound like pyramid pyramid model where functions cascading down the chain. Is this  discouraged? I seem to recall that way but I maybe wrong.
- The 2nd approach let the external client module access its sub-components directly, not sure if this is entirely bad?

Please consider the constituents objects are many more than just two robot arms above and it has more methods.

Comment: I vote for the second approach. This allows you to implement tools like `Rotate(Arm& arm) { arm.move(..); arm.move(..); }`. And you could pass either arm. This would not be possible with the integrated facade (yes, it is a facade). In the end, it depends on your needs. You might also consider returning only the necessary interfaces for the arms (e.g. `IMoveable`), not the entire arm. You might even restrict access to the arms with accessor methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's usually better to encapsulate data and behavior and let each class maintain it so you don't create strong relationships between them.
So the best would be that the View calls Robot.MoveLeftArm and RobotMoveRightArm and the Robot is the one that would send the message down to the Arms which would execute the actual movement.
This way the call and implementation of the arm moving is encapsulated in the Arm and it could change without affecting the View.
There are also options to have interfaces define the behavior and have the classes actually implement that behavior, thus creating a contract between them.

Comment: I completely agree. Ultimately, it boils down to the ["Tell, Don't Ask"](http://coding-is-like-cooking.info/2013/05/tell-dont-ask-object-oriented-design/ "Tell, Don't Ask - Object Oriented Design") philosophy of object-oriented design.

Comment: Thanks yet on the other side even .net/C# uses things like `System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")' which would be almost unimaginable to provide all the wrapper functions for all its sub-components. Makes me wonder if they can do it?